# Datagridview Cannot set Column <ColumnName> to be null

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that bounds data from `DataTable` and it has a column named **BOMOperationID**. This field is being populated based on the `Combobox`selected value. everything is working  except if I will select the first item in the combobox.

Here is my code:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(cbOutwork.SelectedValue) != 0)
{
    BOMOutwork.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["BOMOperationID"].Value = cbOutwork.SelectedValue;
}
else
{
    BOMOutwork.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["BOMOperationID"].Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Error: Cannot set Column `BOMOperationID` to be null. Please use `DBNull` instead.

[image]

How to handle this?

Comment: Why do you need else part?

Comment: I only tried that if it works because my original code is only `BOMOutwork.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["BOMOperationID"].Value = cbOutwork.SelectedValue;`. The same error was encountered. that's why I tried the If...Else.. but still not working. I need to set to null because if it's null user can type any thing in the other cell.

Comment: Do you have value in cbOutwork.SelectedValue?

Comment: Yes. i set the first item as 0.

Comment: I still dont understand why do you want to set null ...set as 0 anyhow you are not going to use it, i suppose!

Comment: I also tried to change the condition and set to 0 but still the same error. It's weird.

Comment: If you are getting this error using the posted code, I am guessing there is something else going on. I copied and pasted your code and it worked as expected using `DBNull.Value`. The posted error clearly recommends a solution to use `DBNull.value` which the code appears to do properly. Therefore, I question this error coming from what little posted code there is.

Comment: It only works when the datagridview is not bounded by `DataTable`.

Comment: In my test I used a `DataGridView` with a `DataTable` as a `DataSource` and it appears to work.

Comment: I already resolved it. I added `CAST(BOMOperationID As varchar(50))` in the query to populate the `DataGridView`. Then handled `dgv_DataError` event using `e.ThrowException = false;`. i do not know if this is valid but it's already working. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already resolved it. I added `CAST(BOMOperationID As varchar(50))` in the query to populate the `DataGridView`. Then handled `dgv_DataError` event using `e.ThrowException = false;`. i do not know if this is valid but it's already working. Thanks everyone.